# Solving inequality based on growth rates of functions

Tags: limits, inequality

I've been wondering if given an inequality 
$f(x_1) < g(x_1)$ 
for a given value of $x_1$, where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both increasing, have the same domain, $x_1$ is in this domain and given that 
$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = c < 1$ 
where $c$ is a constant, can I conclude that inequality above is true for all values of $x > x_1$ in the domain? 
I'll be grateful for any help! 
 Michael

Comment: Let the domain be $(5,\infty)$, $f(x) = \ln(2x-10)+3$, and $g(x) = 2\ln(x)$.  Then your conditions are met, but $f(20) > g(20)$.

Comment: @Eric Towers ok, I see. What if the functions intersect the x-axis at the same point though? By the way I edited my question because I wanted to know if that inequality holds for $x > x_1$, where $x_1$ is the given number for which the inequality is true.

Comment: My example also works here.  Use $x_1 = 5.1$: $f(5.1) < g(5.1)$.  Twenty is certainly bigger than $5.1$.